# Chrome.downloads.download in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Chrome is telling me that chrome.downloads is undefined when I try to use it in my app.

Here is a simple example where I am trying to download an image...

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Downloader",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "permissions": ["downloads", "<all_urls>"],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <button id="download">Download</button>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600}
    }
  );
});
```

Main.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#download").addEventListener("click",
    function () {
      chrome.downloads.download({
        url: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Moonbeam_UFO.JPG",
        filename: "ufo.jpg"
      });
    }
  );
};
```

There are similar posts about trying to get the downloads object working when developing extensions, but I can't find anything about using it in an app. Has anyone been able to use this successfully, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There is a good chance I am not using the api correctly, but I don't make it that far because Chrome gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'download' of undefined"

Comment: Also, entering "chrome.downloads" in the chrome console returns "undefined"

Comment: Does https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/window-state work for you? If so, it might be worth using that as a new starting point to slot in your own functionality instead.

Comment: Looks like the downloads API is not supported in apps. compare: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index

Comment: This is exactly it. I have bookmarked the wrong API page. I'm an idiot. Thanks

Comment: @levi Please make that into an answer.

Comment: But is this not a Chrome Extension and not a Chrome app? At least it looks very much like a Chrome Extension? I am trying to do the same, but "chrome.downloads" is "undefined" and I am following a tutorial on Chrome Extensions and it should be supported here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) API is not yet supported in Chrome apps ([crbug.com/274673](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=274673)).

But you can still trigger a file download with the standard APIs of the web platform. In fact, the logic from your question can completely be replicated with pure HTML:

```
<a download="ufo.jpg" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Moonbeam_UFO.JPG">Download</a>
```

(styling the anchor as a button is left as an exercise to the reader)

Comment: The problem i see with using this approach to download the file is, the downloaded files goes directly to the default download location. Is there some way i can specify where the download file will be saved ?

Comment: @Gaurav_soni No, you cannot specify the target directory in this way. But if you are the user, then you can visit the Settings page, Advanced and tick the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" checkbox. Another app-only way to save a file is to use the [`chrome.fileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) API.

Comment: I tried using chrome.fileSystem API but without success. What i basically need is i click a button , bunch of files download and save locally for offline use. Please suggest what to do. Thanks