# Chrome extension: get downloaded file content manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

How can I get content (byte array / readable stream) from downloaded file after migrating to manifest 3?*

With manifest 2 I got it with XMLHttpRequest, but now it's disabled and fetch can't work with local files.

Comment: `fetch` works with local files [since Chrome 99](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/268e65004215716c3957b229794357da23acaf2d).

Comment: @wOxxOm It appears that you also need to uncheck "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in chrome://settings/downloads; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485582/2336725